# Biblatex no extra line, in case of equal initial letters

Tags: biblatex

My Bibliography is arranged like in the example beneath. So the equal initial letters are merged together (without extra line in between). How I'm able to have an extra line in any cases?

```
    Kieviet, André (Lean Digital Transformation, 2019): Lean Digital Transformation: Ge­ schäftsmodelle transformieren, Kundenmehrwerte steigern und Effizienz erhöhen, Wies­ baden, 2019

    Prof. Dr. Bonin, Holer, Dr. Gregory, Terry, Dr. Zierahn, Ulrich (Übertragung auf Deutsch­ land, 2015): Übertragung der Studie von FreyOsborne 2013 auf Deutschland, in: Kurz­ expertise (2015), Nr. 57
    Prof. Dr. Kagermann, Henning, Prof. Dr. Wahlster, Wolfgang, Dr. Helbig, Johannes, M.A. Hellinger, Ariane, M.A. Stumpf, Veronika (Digitalisierung Industrie, 2013): Di­ gitalisierung der Industrie – Die Plattform Industrie 4.0, Frankfurt am Main, 2013

    Rische, Marie­Christin, Vöpel, Henning (Digitalökonomie, 2016): Schwerpunkt Kreative Zerstörung 4.0 ­ Die Neuvermessung der Welt ­ Grundprinzipien und Konsequenzen der Digitalökonomie, in: Wirtschaftspolitische Blätter (2016), Nr. 2
```

---

```
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=ext-authoryear,
    maxcitenames=3,
    maxbibnames=999,
    mergedate=false,
    date=iso,
    seconds=true,
    urldate=iso,
    innamebeforetitle,
    dashed=false,
    autocite=footnote,
    doi=false,
    useprefix=true,
    mincrossrefs = 1
]{biblatex}
\input{modBib}
...
\printbibliography[nottype=online,heading=bibintoc,title={Literaturverzeichnis}]
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)

Comment: Probably something in your preamble sets `\bibinitsep` to a non-zero value, try setting `\bibitemsep` instead. `\bibitemsep` is inserted between all entries, while `\bibinitsep` is only inserted between entries with different initial letter. If you want more specific help (and want help that has been tested), please show us a short, compilable example document that reproduces what you are seeing at the moment (a so-called MWE https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 or MWEB https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864).

Comment: Note that it is *extremely* uncommon to include academic titles and degrees in names in the bibliography. In the example all Prof. Dr.s  are sorted under 'P' which is probably quite unhelpful. And unless you are really careful in the input, the names might also be mangled/misparsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`biblatex` has three parameters to adjust the spacing *between* entries (§3.11.4 *Lengths and Counters*, p. 131, v3.15a of [the `biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)).

- `\bibitemsep` is the space inserted between individual entries.
- `\bibnamesep` is the space inserted between entries by different authors/editors.
- `\bibinitsep` is the space inserted between entries with different initial letter of the authors/editors.

Note that if several of those spaces would apply between two entries, the largest space wins. The spaces are not added.

The result you describe in the question looks like the result of setting `\bibinitsep` to a non-zero value, e.g.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\setlength{\bibinitsep}{2\itemsep}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,nussbaum,knuth:ct:a,
  knuth:ct:b,kastenholz,aksin,herrmann}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography with space between entries with different first letters.]

You can change this by setting `\bibnamesep` to 0. If you want more space between all entries, set `\bibitemsep` to a larger value.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot moewe, you nailed it. It works fine with \bibitemsep instead of \bibinitsep, if this will help someone, someday I set: \setlength{\bibitemsep}{0.75cm}. Also thanks for the hint about academic titles, I will double check this one.